# How can i do lazy loading images on vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Hi guys i made giphy search app but images loading slowly how can i make it lazy loading?

live: https://giphse.vercel.app/
src: https://github.com/korayguler/giphse

Answer (score -2):

You can use **[vue-lazyload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-lazyload)** library to do this.

1- First, install the packege using npm:

```
npm i vue-lazyload
```

2- After that add VueLazyload plugin to your Vue App:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueLazyload from 'vue-lazyload'
 
Vue.use(VueLazyload)
 
// or with options
Vue.use(VueLazyload, {
  preLoad: 1.3,
  error: 'dist/error.png',
  loading: 'dist/loading.gif',
  attempt: 1
})
 
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: {
    App
  }
})
```

3- Then you can use it every where:

```js
<ul>
  <li v-for="img in list">
    <img v-lazy="img.src" >
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But vue-lazyload only running vue 1 and 2

Comment: Vue-Lazyload doesn't support VueJS 3